# Не работает * в ls при запуске через execpv

Tags: c++, linux, c

Пробую запустить команды ls и cp через execpv.

```
char* argv[]=
{
    "/usr/bin/ls",
    "-l",
    "/home/chorkov/*",
    nullptr
};
execvp(*argv,argv);
```

получаю сообщение об ошибке `/usr/bin/ls: cannot access '/home/chorkov/*': No such file or directory`. Из командной строки - команда работает. При отсутствии звездочки среду аргументов - тоже работает. Аналогично ведет себя cp (выдает ошибку `cp: cannot stat '/home/chorkov/*.csv': No such file or directory`, при наличии звездочки вместо конкретного файла). Не могу сообразить куда дальше копать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подстановку `*` делает `bash`, не сама программа. Вот так сработает:

```
char *argv[] = {
    "bash",
    "-c",
    "/usr/bin/ls -l /home/chorkov/*",
    nullptr
};
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```